# Why are the segments parallel?

Tags: geometry

I'm studying secondary elements of triangles.

[image]

If $F$ is midpoint of $AC$ and $D$ is midpoint of $AB$, then:

$1) FD \parallel CB$

$2) FD = \frac{CB}{2}$

I have tried to demonstrate this, but I have not reached any conclusion, even on the internet I have only found these same properties, but not a demonstration with their analysis.

So, what is the proof of this? And if you know any book with geometric demonstrations of the properties of the triangles, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Please improve the title, at least. It is utterly meaningless, at the moment.

Comment: @Thanks Jack, was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all notice that there is a typo in

$$2) FD = 2 * CB$$

and the correct version should have been

$$ 2) CB = 2 * FD$$

For the proof notice that the triangle $ABC$ is similar to the triangle $ADF$ with a similarity ratio of $2:1$,  $( SAS )$

Thus the third sides have the same ratio and the  other two angles are equal  so you get parallel lines with one twice the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know any good book? Tell me abou geometric demonstrations and things like that?

Comment: Euclidean Geometry: A First Course
By Mark Solomonovich


Also available as: E-Book
Published: August 2010
Format: Perfect Bound Softcover(B/W)
Pages: 408
Size: 8.25x11
ISBN: 9781440153488

Comment: Many thanks Mohammad :D